# Scoping issues when importing modules, can't access method at run time

Tags: kendo-ui, requirejs, typescript, amd

I know we are doing something fundamentally wrong, hopefully someone in the community can point it out.

Basically we can't call the 'showError' member method declared in this module at run-time. It looks like a life time or scoping issue, but the code is below:

stakeHolderViewModel.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../../../Scripts/typings/requirejs/require.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../../Scripts/typings/kendo-ui/kendo.all.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../datasources/stakeholderdatasource.ts" />

import kendo = require("kendo");
import stakeholderDatasource = require("../Datasources/stakeholderDatasource");
import stakeholderModel = require("../Models/stakeholderModel");

var module = {
    viewModel: new kendo.data.ObservableObject({ ... this is OK ... }),

    loadData: (id, router) => { ... this is OK too ... },

    showError: (err) => {  // this is the method  that is not callable at runtime!
       window.console.error(err);
   }
}

export = module;
```

We then import this module and try to access the showError method from this module here:

stakeholderDatasource.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../../../Scripts/typings/requirejs/require.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../../Scripts/typings/kendo-ui/kendo.all.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../models/stakeholdermodel.ts" />
/// <reference path="../viewmodels/stakeholderviewmodel.ts" />

import kendo = require("kendo");
import stakeholderModel = require("../Models/stakeholderModel");
import indexViewModel = require("../ViewModels/stakeholderViewModel");

//TODO: make below path relative...
var crudBaseUrl = "/api/Reference/ReferenceApiController/";

var stakeholderDatasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
transport: { ... all OK ... },
pageSize: 25,
schema: { ... all OK here too ... },
error(err) {
      console.log(indexViewModel);        
      indexViewModel.showError(err); // Error on this call!
  }
});

export = stakeholderDatasource;
```

At run-time we get the following error:

[image: error!]

It compiles OK, and we get intellisence at design time, so we are a little confused.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You must be wrong!  What does the generated js file look like?  There is no showError function?  No syntax errors?

Comment: Actually your syntax is wrong in you example!  What is "error" supposed to be?  Maybe error: (err) => {...}?